# Filter by tags AEM 6.5

Tags: java, aem

I am supposed to filter thru experience fragments by tags. User selects filters(tags) as per their needs and the search return experience fragments with matching tags.
Any ideas how to retrieve the selected filters(tags) and see what matches the existing tags and return corresponding EF? Basically the whole process. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing custom logic to search the EF with related tags, then you can query the repository for the custom tags. Tags will be added as cq:tags property. You can write a query using QueryBuilder API something like below. Here I am searching through the /content for content tagged with workflow:dam. You can change the path to your EF path and the `property.value` should be the value your users enter as tags.

```
path=/content
property=cq:tags
property.value=workflow:dam
```

[Tags saved in the content repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yQMk.png)